# Most elegant way to share a C array

Tags: c, global-variables

I have to turn back to (embedded) C after some lengthy time with C++, and have the following problem:

I have a source module which is included a lot of times, let's call it `utilities.h` and `utilities.c`
In it, I have an important array, let's call it

```
#define IMPORTANT_ARRAY_LENGTH  10000
char important_array[IMPORTANT_ARRAY_LENGTH];
```

I have a lot of other functions in this `utilities` module, and they all work fine. However, in one of the other source files, let's call it `worker.c`, I have to use this array. What is the "official", elegant way to do this, without having to put `extern char important_array[IMPORTANT_ARRAY_LENGTH]` and the macro definition in the `worker.c` ?

If I do the following:

utilities.h

```
#ifndef _UTILITIES_H_
#define _UTILITIES_H_

#define IMPORTANT_ARRAY_LENGTH  10000
extern char important_array[IMPORTANT_ARRAY_LENGTH];

// ...
```

utilities.c

```
#ifndef _UTILITIES_C_
#define _UTILITIES_C_

#include "utilities.h"

char important_array[IMPORTANT_ARRAY_LENGTH];

// ...
```

worker.c

```
#include "utilities.h"
// ...
important_array[0] = 0;
```

then my array will be an undefined symbol in `worker.c`. If I don't use the `extern` keyword in `utilities.h`, then of course, it's a duplicate symbol. (Strangely, it compiles with just a warning, and I can see from the linker file that the size is allocated multiple times.)

Do I really have to declare my array in `worker.c`? I want to keep everything clean, and have all declarations in one place only: in a header file. And I want to have the macro definition only once (this is secondary, because I could use a const, but I want the preprocessor to handle it, and not take up place)

Comment: declare it in `utilities.h`. If the compiler complain about "undefined symbol", you have another problem. How do you compile it?

Comment: I do declare it in `utilities.h`. My question is about `worker.c`.

Comment: BTW: don't use leading underscores in preprocessor symbols, unless you are part of the implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is the canonical way to do it: have an `extern` declaration in the header file, and define the variable in the `.c` file.

> my array will be an undefined symbol in worker.c

No, it won't. Your code will compile and link just fine.

Comment: This was not the question. As you can see I already did it like this. The question was about how to use it in another translation unit.

Comment: @vsz: You just go ahead and use it; there's nothing further to be done. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @vzs Well, your question was about the most elegant way to do it. With this approach, you just #include the header file. As that's not working for you, you're doing something wrong somewhere else, or your compiler is broken.

Comment: I use it exactly as it's in the example. Do you mean it is syntactically correct, and I'll have to fiddle with the project settings?

Comment: @vsz: You have to link `utilities.c` into your executable. Beyond that, no special "fiddling of project settings" is required.

Comment: I have no explicit makefile, this is why I mentioned the project file. It works now as you said, if I link everything correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I often put the definition in the header (this is frowned upon, I know).
It keeps the definition and declaration close together, which is a Good Thing.

```
/* file.c */
#define FILE_C 1
#include "file.h"
```

.

```
/* file.h */
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H 1

#define BIG_SIZE 13

#if FILE_C 
char the_array[BIG_SIZE];
#else
extern char the_array[BIG_SIZE];
#endif

#endif /* FlLE_H */
```

.

```
 /* other_file.c */
#include "file.h"
```

There is no risk of doing it wrong: the linker will complain if you do it wrong.

BTW a similar way to basically do the same, but maybe a bit more readable, is:

```
/* file.h */
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H 1

#if FILE_C
#define EXTERN /**/
#else
#define EXTERN extern
#endif

#define BIG_SIZE 13

EXTERN char the_array[BIG_SIZE];

...

#undef EXTERN
#endif /* FlLE_H */
```

Comment: You could use a macro name like `AND_ALSO_DEFINE_STUFF` (or words to that effect) rather than `FILE_C`. Just so that file.c is explicitly telling the header to provide definitions, rather than making it look like file.h is the one that knows what .c file they should be in.

Comment: That's also a possibility, it's only a name. ALSO_DIFINE stuff is not a very discriptive name. I'd prefer DO_DEFINE_THE_BIG_ARRAY. But what if there is more than one item defined in the .h file? The FILE_C macro name directly indicates where it is supposed to be defined, which again is a Good Thing. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Having one declaration (`extern...`) in each translation unit and exactly one definition is the most elegant way to do this.

So leave the `extern char important_array` in the header and `char important_array` in one of the `.c` files.

Comment: I know, but this does not answer my question. Do I have to put `extern char important_array` in **all** the `.c` files which include the headers?

Comment: @vsz It does answer your question. declaration in the header, definition in one .c file. Read the second line again ?

Comment: @cnicutar: appearantly, it doesn't. In the example I wrote, I have the declaration in the header, the definition in the `.c` file, and I include the header in translation unit where I want to use it, but I still get the `undefined symbol` error, although I include the header. This header is included in other units as well, so it might be that in this translation unit (`worker.c` in my example) it is already jumped out because of the #define _UTILITIES_H_

Comment: @vsz Sounds like a linker error - show us how you're linking it. Also, what's with the `#ifndef _UTILITIES_C_` stuff ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new function at utilities.c called something like "get_important_array" that just returns a pointer to array and put the prototype at utilities.h.  After that, when you put the utilities.h at worker.c you'll have important_array access in a simple, and organized way.