# Issue with Global Variables in Header File

Tags: c, variables, global, chess

I'm making a chess engine, and I'm trying to store several 8x8 arrays for board representation (e.g a White Rook array, with 0s being non rooks and 1s being a white rook)

The idea is by me making it global, I never have to pass it in any functions, I can just make it global and access it from and function, and any change I make to those arrays will change for all functions. However I'm getting duplicate symbol errors on all of my variables. Here's a sample of the errors

```
duplicate symbol _whiteQueens in:
    /Users/mkerian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/chessGameST-         ggkdsdjczjelcyftciubhwejdbma/Build/Intermediates.noindex/chessGameST.build/Debug/chessGameST.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/boardRep.o
```

In case it's necessary here is my declaration code.

```
int allChars[8][8];
int whiteChars[8][8]; 
int blackChars[8][8];

int whitePawns[8][8];
int blackPawns[8][8];

int whiteKnights[8][8];
int blackKnights[8][8];

int whiteBishops[8][8];
int blackBishops[8][8];
```

It seems to be a build time error. If you guys have any ideas of things I could to solve this I'd appreciate it!

EDIT: I've made a few changes which has changed my issue a little bit

In my header file, I defined the arrays like

```
extern int allChars[8][8];
```

I did that for all of my global variables. I have ~6 .c files I'm using in this program, it seems like my errors are only for one of them per variable. e.g. main isn't throwing an error for the variables, but everything else is. How can I take one global variable, but then be able to use it for all of my .c?

Comment: "here is my declaration code." That code is not only declaring but also defining the variables.

Comment: @StoryTeller, the marked duplicate focuses on the difference between `extern t_opp* gl_opptab` and `extern t_opp gl_opptab[]`. That is maybe not a suitable duplicate candidate.

Comment: @Gerhardh, thanks for the comment! Do you mind explaining a little more what you mean. I thought declaring would be like
    
      int x; While defining would be like int x = 5;

Comment: No, both are definitions. One with initialization. A second question was added as duplicate. There you can find more information.

Comment: @Gerhardh Hey, thanks for the help! Sorry I'm being so dense about this. Right now I have `extern int ply;` in my header file. In all my of .c files I put `int ply`. 
It has reduced the amount of duplicate items from 115 to 85 when I compile, but I still have a bunch of issues with duplicate objects. Obviously I didn't just put extern for ply, I put it for all of my global variables.
Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: You may only have one .c file with a definition per variable. Also no initialization in the header. You might add the changed code  to your question

Comment: @Gerhardh I went ahead and made an edit. If you have any ideas on what I can do I'd highly appreciate it! I'm stumped here unfortunately, I hadn't even learned about extern yet

Comment: I think, this question tells everything necessary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395134/most-elegant-way-to-share-a-c-array : One C file with definition, all other C files only use it. And all `external` declarations go into the header.